# How to replace an empty date value?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replace many null date values in a single column using this query:

```
UPDATE animal SET
  BirthDate = '1900-01-01 06:00:00 AM' 
WHERE BirthDate = '''
```

MySQL shows this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE animal SET
>     BirthDate = '1900-01-01 06:00:00 AM' 
>   WHERE BirthDate = ''' at line 1.

How can this be resolved? I use Toad for MySQL interface editor.

Comment: In this script BirthDate on ``where`` clause is equals to ' ?
Try '' or is null

Comment: What datatype is `BirthDate`?

Comment: The `AM` on the end is ignored.  This means that if you have `PM`, you will get the wrong time.

Answer (score 1):

- For starters, your GUI shouldn't matter, but it's normally good to use the CLI - i.e. the `mysql` client - or at least as a backup in case of results you are having problems interpreting.
- Second, have you tried `IS NULL` instead of the `=` comparison?
- Third, what's wrong with `NULL`? Normally, you should use the appropriate datatype - why is `NULL` a problem? If you don't know the date of birth, there's nothing wrong with it. For example, if you want to perform an `AVG` calculation, you'll have problems. Your population will appear much older than it really is. `NULL`s however will be ignored in such a calculation, so no anomalous results (the same goes for all such calculations).